# How to question someone

Tags: questions, syntax, idiomatic-language

Which of the following is more correct and native way of questioning someone ?

> "Where does you learn all this from"
>
> "From where do/does you learn all this"

And if both of them are wrong then please let me know correct way of questioning someone

Comment: *Does you* is impossible: *does* is third person singular only.

Answer (score 2):

Once you correct "does" to "do", both are grammatical.

However ...

> Where do you xxx from?

is normal in most people's speech, whereas

> From where do you xxx?

is rather formal and stilted, and not many people would say it.

I have removed "learn all this" from my examples, because I think "Where do you learn all this from" is an unlikely thing for a native English speaker to say, for two separate reasons.

First, that would only be used in a habitual sense, implying that you regularly go and learn this. If you are referring to a particular body of knowledge, then

> Where did you learn all this?

or (less likely)

> Where have you learnt all this?

Secondly, as you can see from those examples, I don't find the "from" likely with "learn" (though it is possible0.